# PHP Process to process smaller batches

Tags: php, mysql

I have a nice little script that is very primetive and currently will run fine in php cli. If I tried to load it up on the apache server, it will give me an error that it times out, or couldnt process the directive. Currently the php file is parsing a page for a specific part of HTML on it.

Is there any way to have it do small batches or make the process faster? I have around 500-800 urls that need to be processed.

```
include('./db.php');

$query = "SELECT id,link FROM `1710` order by id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $link = $row['link'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $parse = preg_replace("/htt.{1,2}:\/\/(.+?[\.\-])*(\w{1,61}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})\/.*/i", "$2", $link);
        if ($parse == 'curseforge.com') {
            $html = file_get_contents($link);
            preg_match('%<li class="view-on-curse">\s+<a href="http:\/\/curse\.com\/project\/(?P<id>.*)">\s+View on Curse\.com\s+<\/a>\s+<\/li>%', $html, $matches);
            echo 'https://widget.mcf.li/project/' . $matches['id'] . '.json <br />';

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pile more and more jobs into a single script run and expect that to work forever. Take a look at a "job queuing system", either one ready to use or something you implement yourself. It allows you to register small batches of jobs (typically in a database) and then process them in a controlled and transparent manner.

Comment: I guess its time to move to a MVC framework or something. This little project is getting a little big without one.

Comment: Hm, I don't really see a connection here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at extending the time that the script is allowed to run

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
<?php
set_time_limit (300);  // 5 minutes
```